# regular expression which will allow string "site 6 camp 101"

Tags: javascript, java, regex

Looking for the regular expression which will allow "site 6 camp 101" or "site6 camp 101" word spaces number words or space or number onwards

Allowed

Site6
Site6 camp101
site 6 camp 101

Now Allowed

```
Site camp
```

after first word and space only number will be allowed.I have tried code below:

```
^[A-Za-z]+[0-9 ]+[A-Za-z 0-9]+
```

not working as expected

Comment: Do you need exactly the words "site" and "camp" or whatever words?

Comment: any alphabets are fine

Comment: `^[A-Za-z]{4} ?[0-9 ]+[A-Za-z]+ ?[0-9]+` perhaps? https://regex101.com/

Comment: Hi anubhava, Sorry, this should allowed site6 or site 6 as well your expression is not allowing it

Comment: in other words it should not be mandatory to have any words after site6 or site 6

Comment: [Then you can use `^[A-Za-z]+\s*[0-9]+(?:[ \t]+[a-zA-Z]+\s*[0-9]+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/XVBEOn/2)

Comment: Thank you anubhava.

Answer (score 1):

Define an optional space between "Site" and "6", and remove the space from `[0-9 ]` :

```
    ^[a-zA-Z]+ ?[0-9]+[a-zA-Z\d ]+
--- Here -----^
```

This matches :

- Site6 camp101
- site 6 camp 101

And doesn't match :

- Site camp

Same thing shorter, using `\w` (any alphanumeric) and `\d` (digits only):

```
^\w+ ?\d+[\w ]+
```

**Edit** after your new requirement

Since the regex should also allow `some6`, make whatever's after that (optional)? :

```
^\w+ ?\d+([\w ]+)?
```

Matches :

- Site6
- Site6 camp101
- site 6 camp 101

Does not match :

- Site camp

Comment: Hello Jeremy, this is working only problem is it is not allowing site6 sorry i should have mention in the question itself.

Comment: in other words it should not be mandatory to have any words after site6 or site 6

Answer (score 1):

Translating my comments to an answer.

You may use this regex:

```
^[A-Za-z]+\s*[0-9]+(?:[ \t]+[a-zA-Z]+\s*[0-9]+)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XVBEOn/2/)

- `\s*` before first `[0-9]+` makes first space optional
- Regex expression inside `(?...)?` is an optional match.